# Задать свою ширину колонок в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

написал вот такой код

```
    .wrap{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
}

.header-top{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #349d4a;
    min-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-margin{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.logo{
    background-image: url("img/logo.jpg");
    width: 126px;
    height: 59px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.telephone{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: rgb( 52, 157, 74 );
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.cost-call{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb( 34, 34, 34 );
    display: block;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.telephone{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.work-time{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.back-call{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgb( 52, 157, 74 );
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #349d4a;
    width: 120px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.basket{
    width: 265px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #e5ffea;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.margin-left{
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6"><div class="logo"></div> </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 margin-left">
        <span class="telephone">+7 (800) 700-73-94</span><br>
        <span class="cost-call">(звонок бесплатный)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 margin-left">
        <span class="telephone">+7 (965) 144-08-77</span><br>
        <span class="cost-call">для юр лиц</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 margin-left">
        <span class="work-time">
            Режим работы: <br>
            пн-пт с 10:00 до 18:00<br>
            <span class="back-call">Перезвоните мне</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 margin-left">
        <div class="basket">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

А вопрос заключается вот в чем: Если взять класс logo, то получается, что он занимает слишком много места если родительскому диву задать col-md-2, но при этом если ему задать col-md-1 то на логотип наедут соседние поля, так как мне задать логотипу именно ту ширину, которая необходима мне?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0k3r3o5/)

Comment: А что мешает кастомизировать Bootstrap под свои потребности, и задать ширину колонок свою.

Answer (score 1):

Переопределить бутстраповские стили либо вообще не использовать их задавая свою ширину. Как вариант, настроить всю сетку под свои нужды http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ (очень грубый вариант)